# When I quit Adventure Capitalist I lose moon progress (PC)

Tags: adventure-capitalist

So whenever I invest my 1 decillion into the moon it starts the countdown but then when I quit and re-open I lose my 1 decillion but the count down has reset!! This has been very frustrating and is there any way to fix this?

Comment: As long as you waited a few seconds before closing the game, it should be saving like normal. Have you submitted a bug to the developer?

Comment: Since only that resets, it just sounds like it doesn't trigger the save. What happens if you start the countdown timer, then buy something else?

Comment: @DangerZone I waited a couple seconds and I bought more stuff. The stuff saved but the mission reset. How do I submit a bug?

Comment: @Katamaritaco ^^

Comment: @Bucky, [here is the Kongergate's contact page.](http://www.kongregate.com/feedbacks/new) Just submit a message describing the issue and set the subject to mobile bug report. There is also a forum topic for bug reports on the main page.

Comment: @DangerZone I'm playing on my PC can I still submit the bug there?

Comment: Probably, I would just check and see if there is a more appropriate subject on the "contact us" form. The forum should be ok for any platform though.

Comment: Decillion? On mobile at least the Moon launch is a couple trillion.